# Why layer in model subclassing doesn't get inputs ,how can i edit its shape?

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow2.0, color-space, image-classification

**This is an example**

This suffer me also when i try to use Subclassing model

call method input can't feed my model but I don'know why I had something like this code but it run briefly good

Base problem is in call method at :                   conv_input = layer(conv_input)

```
color_spaces = ["RGB" ,"YUV" ,"XYZ"]

class BlockCNN(keras.models.Model):
      
      def __init__(self,image_width=224, image_height=224 ,color_space="RGB" ,**kwargs):
```

.
.
.

```
      def call(self ,inputs):
          conv_block_output = []

          inp = self.rescale_(inputs[0]) ,inputs[1]
          inp = self.augument(inp[0]), inp[1]

          if self.color_space=="YUV":
            inp = yuv_layer(inp[0]) ,inp[1]
          elif self.color_space=="XYZ":
            inp = xyz_layer(inp[0]) ,inp[1]
           
          # Convolution 
          conv_input = inp
          print(conv_input)
          for layer in self.blocks["start_block"] :
              conv_input = layer(conv_input)
              conv_input_top = conv_input
              conv_input_bot = conv_input

        
          return conv_block_output[0] ,conv_block_output[1]
```

**Base class:**
this class use previous class in call method

```
class ColorNet(keras.models.Model):
      
      def __init__(self,image_width=224, image_height=224 ,spaces=["RGB","YUV","XYZ"],num_classes=15,num_fc_unit = 48, num_fc=3,**kwargs):
          super().__init__(**kwargs)
          self.spaces = spaces
          self.num_classes=num_classes
          self.space_1 = BlockCNN(image_width,image_height,spaces[0])
          self.space_2 = BlockCNN(image_width,image_height,spaces[1])
          self.space_3 = BlockCNN(image_width,image_height,spaces[2])
          self.concat = Concatenate()
          self.fc_layers = [Flatten(), Dense(units=4096, activation='relu')  ,Dropout(0.6) 
             ,Dense(units=4096, activation='relu') ,Dropout(0.6)
             ,Dense(units=num_classes, activation='softmax')
          ]
      def call(self ,inputs):
          inp_1 ,inp_2=self.space_1(inputs)
          inp_3, inp_4=self.space_2(inputs)
          inp_5 ,inp_6=self.space_3(inputs)
          inp = self.concat([inp_1 ,inp_2,inp_3 ,inp_4,inp_5,inp_6])
          output = inp
          for layer in self.fc_layers :
              output = layer(output)
          return output

model = ColorNet()
model(next(iter(train_ds)))
```

**error**

```
Call arguments received:
  • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 15), dtype=float32)')
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

create custom layer ([custome layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers)):

```
color_spaces = ["RGB" ,"YUV" ,"XYZ"]

class BlockCNN(keras.layers.Layer):
      
    def __init__(self,image_width=224, image_height=224 ,color_space="RGB" ,**kwargs):
        super(BlockCNN, self).__init__()
        self.image_w = image_width
        self.image_h = image_height
        self.color_s = color_space
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        if self.color_s == 'XYZ':
            inputs = tfio.experimental.color.rgb_to_xyz(inputs)
        
        return inputs
```

Use custome layer:

```
class SuperModel(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self, num_classes=1):
    super(SuperModel, self).__init__()
    self.block_1 = BlockCNN(color_space="XYZ")

def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.block_1(inputs)
    return x

# create model 
model = SuperModel()

# test process 
for img, label in dataset_train:
    x = model(img)
```

Also, if you do not have to, I would stay with [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional)

---

OLD:

If you want to use tf.data to create pipeline you can do something like this:

```
# create dataset where images == path
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(paired_train) 
# map dataset as path to images, load_dataset() - read file
dataset_train = (dataset_train
                .map(load_dataset)
                )
# now you have dataset, which you can use in training

# to create augmentation (convert image from rgb to xyz)
def xyz_conversion(image):
    return tfio.experimental.color.rgb_to_xyz(image)

# map your augmentation
dataset_train_a = dataset_train.map(lambda x: xyz_conversion(x))
```

When you just take `image = dataset_train.take(1)` you get

```
<TakeDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(400, 400, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)>
```

then when you use `tfio.experimental.color.rgb_to_xyz(image)`:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<TakeDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(400, 400, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TakeDataset'>) to a Tensor.
```

You can do this

```
for image in dataset_train.take(1):
    sample_image = image
```

, now you get `tf.Tensor` and `tfio.experimental.color.rgb_to_xyz(sample_image )` works fine.

[image]

Comment: I wanna use this converting in my model subclassng inside the def call(self ,images): and in this method it called with my dataset that consist both of labels and features

Comment: Can you edit your post with more specific example ?

Comment: Edited ,please check it again

Comment: So, your objective is to create layer, that can convert img color inside ?

Comment: Yes , Create layer inside model that can change color space (for example RGB to XYZ)of image and also normlize it .